# P-Hacking concern: How valid is it to take statistically significant linear models from two different datasets and compare their coefficients?

Tags: model, model-comparison, p-hacking

I was wondering what if the following process can be considered p value hacking or just bad statistical practice. What I currently have are two subsets of one large parent dataset. These subsets are created based on their group classification (for example disease vs control). Both of these datasets have the same number of responses, and they have $n \gg 1$ responses. They also have the same covariates: say time. So each subset is basically a $n \times m$ matrix ($n$ responses, $m$ time points)

Models have been built between the covariates and each individual response within each subset. So using our previous example, each subset (disease vs control) will have $n$ models for $n$ responses, yielding $2\times n$ models. It is my interest to compare the coefficients between models for the same response variable between disease subjects vs control subjects.

I've managed to statistically determine which models within each subset are significant (corrected for multiple comparisons), but I am unsure how to proceed. In my hand are models that show that the responses vary over time for disease or control subjects, but could I just take the significant ones and then compare the disease and control models head to head?

I'm not interested in comparing models that do not show changes in the response level over time, which was why I did the statistical significance thresholding first. My concern is that by doing so, I have committed the cardinal sin of looking and comparing only significant models, which is a precursor for p-hacking.

Comment: What hypothesis or hypotheses are you trying to test?

Comment: If you have access to the data, it might be simpler to include `group` as a predictor that interacts with all of the other predictors. Then any "significant" interaction coefficient with `group` would indicate that the interacting predictor has a coefficient whose value depends on `group`. With multiple "responses" it also seems like this might benefit from either a formal multivariate (multiple-outcome) analysis or (if these are responses over time) from formal modeling of time as a predictor.

Comment: I don't really understand your reason for significance thresholding. OK otherwise you run some comparisons that are not very exciting. So what?

Comment: @Alexis I'm interested to see if the effect of time on the responses is different between disease and control subjects.  Regarding what EdM said, I've been told to separate the datasets instead of looking at an interaction term. I looked at it regardless and the interaction term was not found to be significant (I ran a two-way ANOVA with group as one factor, and time as the other). With regards to doing a multivaraite analysis, we have n > 1000 responses, so I'm not sure how to make sense of that since it is unfortunately a high dimensional dataset.

Comment: @ChristianHennig I hear you, and that's fair. When writing out the question the exact thought popped up but I wanted to ask since I am still a little confused as to what constitutes p-hacking, since I would also have to correct for multiple comparisons when comparing the models; but now my distribution of coefficients for these models were all found to be significant for one particular question, which (I don't know if it does) could affect how FDR may correct for multiple comparisons

Comment: "I'm interested to see if the effect of time on the responses is different between disease and control subjects." I don't think the significance thresholding helps you at all with this. I suspect this will just throw away information (if rather weak information). (The multiple correction issue to me seems quite different from the thresholding, and the latter may just be a distraction from what you really want to know.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concerns about p-hacking can be an impediment to some types of research. If you are doing a hypothesis generating study then interrogate the data as hard as you like, but recognise that the data's responses to your questions must be treated as suggestions rather than statements of fact. P-hacking is more about what you do with the results of analyses than about what you do with data.

If you test hypotheses that are suggested by exploratory analyses of a dataset using that same dataset then you will have a high rate of false positives and over-estimated effect sizes. That is unavoidable, and 'corrections' for multiple comparisons are often an inefficient and wasteful way to attempt to control that. However, if a study is intended to be a preliminary, hypothesis generating, one then the interesting results will be followed up upon with a new study with new data. The chances of a particular hypothesis being falsely supported two times in a row in two datasets is very low.

It sounds to me like you are doing a preliminary study and in that circumstance you may test as many null hypotheses as you like without p-hacking. Do not use significant/not significant to categorise your results, but the p-values can give you a ranking of the strength of evidence against the various null hypotheses that you test. You may choose any of those that are interesting scientifically for followup studies.

You can read section 3.3 of this open access chapter, [A Reckless Guide to P-values](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/164_2019_286), but I recommend that you read the whole thing.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! You are right, it is an exploratory analysis on a dataset I collected. But I guess I'm still a little lost since am I not "testing" some hypothesis by interrogating the data? Would the only way to stave off from making erroneous claims is to state that it was just an exploratory analysis and further experiments would need to be run (on new data) to test it? If so, then am I making the implicit impication that what I have "found" is suggestive, but due to lack of power it is not a fact?

Comment: @Syuma I believe that you might glean some ideas on how to proceed from the paper that I linked.